# CakePHP hasMany

Tags: cakephp

I have a model for User and a model for Notes.

User Model:

```
class User extends AppModel {
var $name = 'User';
var $hasMany = array(
'Note' 
    );
 }
```

User Controller:

```
public function notesview()
  {
  $allnotes = $this->User->Note->find('all', array('order'=>'Note.created DESC'));
  }
```

View Element:

```
$allnotes = $this->requestAction(array('controller'=>'Users', 'action'=>'notesview'));
foreach($allnotes as $viewnotes):
{
    echo $viewnotes['Note']['notes']; 
    echo "<br>";
    echo $viewnotes['Note']['created'];
    echo "<br>";
    echo $viewnotes['User']['name'];

}
endforeach;
```

Now in the element you can see     " echo $viewnotes['User']['name']; ". I want Name field from User model to be retrieved in this element but i get the following error:

```
Notice (8): Undefined index: User [APP\View\Elements\notes.ctp, line 39]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have the belongsTo relationship set inside your Note model?

So, for example, you would have:

```
<?php
class Note extends AppModel {
    public $belongsTo = array('User');
}
```

Comment: Yes Note belongsTo user.

So do we have to add associations on both the models?

Comment: Thank you Josh for help. Its done :)

Answer (score 1):

Does Note belongsTo User?

```
class Note extends AppModel {
    public $name = 'Note';
    public $belongsTo = array('User');
}
```

Comment: Yes Note belongsTo user.

So do we have to add associations on both the models?

Comment: Yes, you have to specify associations in both models. Please paste us your complete `Note` and `User` model. Maybe even the output of `debug($allnotes)` in your element.

Comment: Thank you Jan for help. Its done :)

Comment: Okay, consider marking my answer as accepted :) glad to help.